# how to get value from key in hashmap java

Tags: java

I have a file like this:

```
"test1" : "value1",
"test2" : "value2"
```

And by using a hashmap I want to read it in a way when ever I call the key it returns value of it. I use this code but when I want to get value from key it returns null.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.properties"));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String parts[] = line.split(":");
            map.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
        }
        in.close();
        String value = (String)map.get("test1");
```

P.S. `System.out.println(map); returns {"test1" = "value1", "test2" = "value2}"`

Comment: You may use `Properties` instead and save your file as a .properties.

Comment: I did that but still it returns null

Comment: `get` expects a key as the parameter, so you should try `map.get("test1")`

Comment: Then you did it wrong. Please provide the proper code to replicate your problem.

Comment: I changed it to test1 but still returns null

Comment: Try with `"test1 "` (yes, blank added on purpose).

Comment: Is your problem related to spacing in the input file? Perhaps you should use `split(" : ")`? Also (which probably isn't part of the problem) you may want to remove the `,` at the end of each line in the input file.

Comment: I think your problem is that in your file you ave quotes and spaces, while in your code you're lacking them in the name of your key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on `System.out.println(map); returns {"test1" = "value1", "test2" = "value2}"`

Then the key is either going to be `"test1"` or `"test1"` (including the quotes and the extra space for the second example).

Trying using `String value = (String) map.get("\"test1\" ");` instead.

This is based on the fact that you are only using `split` to split the `String`, but the `String` contains quote marks and spaces...

```
"test1" : "value1"
       ^ ^
```

The space after `"test1`" and before `"value1"` will included.  You can get rid of these by using `String#trim`

```
map.put(parts[0].trime(), parts[1].trim());
```

Or using `:` as your delimiter.

You can also get rid of the quote marks using something like...

```
map.put(parts[0].replaceAll("\"", "").trim(), parts[1].replaceAll("\"", "").trim());
```

But that comes down to what it is you want...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get values in `HashMap` by its key there is no complexity. You only want to call the `get()` with key. But here you are calling get() by value.

```
String value = (String)map.get("value1"); // wrong
```

change it to.

```
String value = (String)map.get("test1"); // correct
```

But your issue not only that, seems to be your key contain white spaces in tailing.

You can use `trim()` to avoid those leading or tailing white spaces.

```
 map.put(parts[0].trim(), parts[1].trim());
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like

```
String value = (String)map.get("test1");
```